# Find records and their amount in db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I get records from a database and the amount of each record using active record interface? For example I have

```
field_1, value_1
field_1, value_2
field_1, value_3
field_1, value_1
field_1, value_2
```

I should get

```
value_1, 2
value_2, 2
value_3, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
Model.count(:all, :group => 'field_to_count')
```

Answer (score 1):

On activerecord you can just use count at your class model with the conditional

e.g: the amount of people with the role admin

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role
end 


Person.count(:role => 'admin')
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i need. If I have a 5 records which have for example "abc" in exact field and 10 records containing "qwe" in this field i should get

qwe, 10
abc, 5

Comment: Here is example for Rails 3.2. It won't work for earlier version because `pluck` appeared in Rails 3.2: `Person.pluck(:role).uniq.map {|r| {:role => r, :count => Person.where(:role => r).count}}`
And we will get the result like this: `[{:role => 'admin', :count => 2}, ..., {:role => 'myrole', :count => '100'}]`